# Implicit functions and exponentials

Tags: lambert-w, implicit-function

I am working with real numbers and trying to express u as function of x, given the equation:

$x^2-u\,e^u = 4$.

I am a bit lost because of the exponential part. I read something about the Lambert function, so I tried to use it and I have:

$W(u\,e^u) = W(-4+x^2) \implies
u = W(-4+x^2)$

Is that correct? If it is, how do i find the derivative with respect to x? Thanks anyone for the help.

Comment: I corrected the math LaTeX expressions. Most notably, dollar signs were missing.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473437/derivative-of-lambert-w-function

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-ue^u=4$$
$$ue^u=-4+x^2$$
$$u=W(-4+x^2)$$

The [derivative of Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is:
$$\frac{d}{dx}W(x)=\frac{W(x)}{x(1+W(x))},$$
the derivative of $-4+x^2$ is:
$$\frac{d}{dx}-4+x^2=2x.$$

Applying the quotient rule , we get
$$\frac{d}{dx}W(-4+x^2)=\frac{2xW(x^2-4)}{(x^2-4)(1+W(x^2-4))}.$$

We also could use the formula for [implicit differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation):

$$x^2-ue^u=4$$
$$x^2-ue^u-4=0$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}u(x)=-\frac{2x}{-e^u-ue^u}$$