Slopes of intersecting curves that are part of a relation
The relation $y^{(y^x)}-x=0$ consists of two curves that intersect at the point $P=(e^{-1},e^{-e})$. I'm interested in the slopes of these curves at this point. Differentiating the relation and solving for $dy/dx$ gives an expression with indeterminate form 0/0 at $P$. One curve corresponds to $y=x^{1/x}$, and its slope at $P$ is $2e^{2-e}$. The other curve starts near the origin, goes through $P$ and on toward $(1,0)$, and appears to have slope 0 at $P$, but I have not been able to prove this. Methods that work for this problem when the relation is a multinomial equation do not appear to work in this case.
Using Travis Willse's Lambert W function idea to write $y=\exp\left(\frac{W_k(x\log x)}{x}\right)$ for $k=0,-1$, computing $dy/dx$ eventually leads to the indeterminate form $\infty \times 0$ at $P$, because $W_0(x)$ and $W_{-1}(x)$ have vertical tangents at $x=-1/e$. However, a plot of this W function expression for $y$ gives interesting results. The union of plots for $k=0,-1$ gives all solutions to the original equation, but these solutions consist of two apparently smooth curves, and each value of $k$ gives part of one curve and part of the other (like an X split not by its forward and backward slashes, but by the upper V and the lower upside-down V).
I have been able to reduce my problem of showing that one intersecting curve has 0 slope at $P$ to showing that $\lim_{x\rightarrow (1/e)^-} \frac{d}{dx}W_0(x\log x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow (1/e)^+} \frac{d}{dx}W_{-1}(x\log x)=-e$. But, I have not proven this yet.

It might help that we can write the general solution (for $x > 0$) as $y = \exp\left(\frac{W_k(x \log x)}{x}\right)$, where $W_k$ denotes the $k$th branch of the Lambert-W function. The choices $k=-1,0$ give you the real solutions (other branches give nonreal solutions).

Thanks for the idea, Travis. I ran with it a bit with results described above.

You can probably use this derivative formula: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473437/derivative-of-lambert-w-function

Unfortunately, $W_k$'s derivative is undefined at the point I'm interested in. So, it's not obvious to me how to use the work you pointed to.
